# UITextView Text size is auto resized while using the NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

In the `UITextView` text,

before highlight the text, its shown the text size as 16. (in the first image)

after the using the `NSAttributedString` to highlight. highlighted text only show that same size(16) remaining strings show lesser than that the original size (second .

this problem only in the `iPod` and `iPhone` deceive . `iPad` is shown correct format.

[image]

code to highlight the `UITextView` Text

```
 NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:currentTextSize] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:txtview4disp.text];

 int startind=[[dict objectForKey:@"BeginIndexPos"]integerValue];
        int endind=[[dict objectForKey:@"EndIndexPos"]integerValue];
        NSRange rang;
        if (startind>=STARTINDEX&&startind<=ENDINDEX) {
            if (endind>ENDINDEX) {
                int endind2=endind-ENDINDEX;
                rang=NSMakeRange(startind-STARTINDEX, (endind-startind)-endind2);   
            }
            else
                rang=NSMakeRange(startind-STARTINDEX, endind-startind);


        [attrString addAttributes:attrsDictionary range:rang];

        [attrString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:rang];

   txtview4disp.attributedText=attrString;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you skipped the original attributes of your `UITextView`.
Try replacing this line:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:txtview4disp.text];
```

with following:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:txtview4disp.attributedText];
```